# Sidekiq for image processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, delayed-job, sidekiq

I was reading [this article](http://blog.statuspage.io/kicking-ass-with-sidekiq), and came across:

> Because Ruby can only ever be executing one thread at a time, it's not recommended you do any computationally intensive tasks (like image processing) using Sidekiq - Delayed Job would be much more appropriate for that.

For my application, I'm using image processing (and uploading via Carrierwave to S3), but I'm also doing business-logic processing (one of the things is code syntax highlighting from a third-party website).

For performance, should I stick with Sidekiq or should I move to Delayed Job, or should I use a mixture of both?

Answer (score 0):

For most purposes you could use either and if you are careful/proactive you can move from one to another without much hassle.

A point you should remember is that `Sidekiq` requires thread-safe code and libraries. Have a look at this nice comparison of [Ruby background processing libraries](http://www.sitepoint.com/series/comparing-ruby-background-processing-libraries/).

By the way, I think that the article you quoted might have missed a comma. I think the author meant to say:

> [...] you do any computationally intensive tasks (like image processing), using Sidekiq **or** Delayed Job would be much more appropriate for that.